# Is it valid to conduct t-tests with just 20 students?

Tags: t-test, sampling

[By reading](https://www.statology.org/what-is-the-difference-between-a-t-test-and-an-anova/) article I think I found a bug:
[image]

Seams to me that 20 is a very small number of samples in this article assuming 20 students are taken random and the order of students is not important. I [read](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2541/what-references-should-be-cited-to-support-using-30-as-a-large-enough-sample-siz) and it looks to me this question is super important but not treated with great care since it can be a reference to basically any sampling question.

Comment: A $t$-test is designed to deal with small samples.  A big issue with small samples is that tests are not powerful: they are more likely to fail to spot actual differences than tests with larger samples.  In your described experiment, a greater concern might be that students could improve just by taking a second test without the guide and you test will not consider this

Comment: At this time I am just concerned with the number of samples, and your words "not powerful" since these are for reason. Just I would like to have some math quantification for this :)

Comment: The test is valid even for $n=2$ given the assumption of i.i.d. normal differences.

Comment: Our [site search works pretty well for questions concerning basic statistical procedures](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=t+test+small+pair*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it will help to look at a couple of examples
with $n = 20$ differences. A paired t test on
paired observations $(X_{1i}, X_{2i}), i=1,2,\dots,20,$
is the same as a one-sample t test on differences
$Y_i = X_{2i} - X_{1i},$ measuring 'improvement' for
the $i$th student.

Suppose $Y_i$ are as sampled in R below:

```
set.seed(225)
y = round(rnorm(20, 5, 5), 2)
summary(y);  length(y);  sd(Y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -3.060   1.948   4.925   5.208   8.000  14.620 
[1] 20         # sample size
[1] 0.5775886  # sample SD
```

A stripchart shows that the mean $\bar Y = 5.2$ is not  only larger than $0$ but perhaps *convincingly* larger
in terms of the variability of the 20 differences.

```
stripchart(y, pch="|")
 abline(v=0, col="green2", lty="dotted")
```

[image]

A t test of $H_0: \mu_d = 0$ against $H_a: \mu_d \ne 0$
shows a P-value very nearly $0$ so that we reject $H_0$ in favor of $H_a$ at the 5% level of significance (and
at some smaller levels of significance).

```
t.test(y)

        One Sample t-test

data:  y
t = 5.2565, df = 19, p-value = 4.497e-05
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 3.134586 7.282414
sample estimates:
mean of x 
   5.2085
```

In this one instance, a t test based on $n = 20$
observations from a normal population with $\mu$ one
standard deviation $\sigma$ above $0$ seems to have
plenty of power to detect that $\mu > 0.$

The particular sample above was not extraordinary
in this regard, as the brief simulation below in R
shows. About 99% of t tests on such data will reject
$H_0;$ the *power* of the t test in these circumstances
is about 99%.

```
set.seed(2021)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(20,5,5))$p.val)
mean(pv <= 0.05)
[1] 0.98871
```

Here are results from a formal 'power and sample size'
procedure in Minitab. (There is an R library that does
such computations for a variety of commonly used tests, many kinds of statistical software have similar procedures, and there are web sites with reliable 'calculators'.) The accompanying power curve, shows
useful power even for differences as small as $3.$

```
Power and Sample Size 

1-Sample t Test

Testing mean = null (versus > null)
Calculating power for mean = null + difference
α = 0.05  Assumed standard deviation = 5

            Sample
Difference    Size     Power
         5      20  0.996103
```

[image]

However, it is hardly a surprise that the following
sample does not happen to lead to rejection of $H_0.$

```
set.seed(226)
y = round(rnorm(20, 2, 5), 2)
mean(y);  sd(y)
[1] 1.2965
[1] 4.760695
t.test(y)$p.val
[1] 0.2381652   # fail to rej at 5% level
```

Speaking more technically, the power of a t test can be computed using a *noncentral* t distribution as discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/496304/calculate-the-power-of-a-paired-t-test-in-r-manually/496392#496392).

An advantage of paired designs such as yours is that the variability
of differences before and after tends to be small compared with the variability of the performances
of individuals considered only before (or only after).

Addendum per comment:

```
set.seed(2021)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(20,5,10), alt="g")$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
1] 0.69621
```

With $n = 20$ observed differences from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=5, \sigma=10),$
you will have power only about 70% of rejecting the null hypothesis (right-sided test).

Minitab output (without graph):

```
Power and Sample Size 

1-Sample t Test

Testing mean = null (versus > null)
Calculating power for mean = null + difference
α = 0.05  Assumed standard deviation = 10

            Sample
Difference    Size     Power
         5      20  0.695149
```

Comment: Great, I run all the code and I am trying now to sum all up: If you have `pv = replicate(10^3, t.test(rnorm(20,5,10))$p.val)` higher variance and relatively low number of samples like 20, like I altered your original example and set for instance $\sigma=10$, we cannot reject $H_0$

Comment: See addendum to my Answer.

Comment: Thanks @BruceET, if with stick with specific `alternative` parameter, it looks obvious to me that you can control the approval of rejection of the $H_0$ with exactly two numbers: number of samples $n$ in here it was 20 and standard deviation, 10 in the addendum, having significance level of 0.05 as the one that is well accommodated, I cannot recall who was the first person using significance level 0.05 it, but I guess last name started on either P. or N. Which can lead me to the spectacular quest: 
```set.seed(2021)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(30,0,1))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)```

Comment: Of why 30 is so important but I cannot ask more questions I reached the limit. Some other time. :)

Comment: The so-called 'rule of thirty', waaay too often quoted without good reason, is largely bogus. Nothing special about 30. (Your life will be better if you forget you ever heard of it.) For sufficiently large $n,$ z tests and t tests can become very similar. But for normal or nearly normal data the difference is to use z if $\sigma$ is known and t if $\sigma$ is estimated by sample SD $S.$ If $n$ is large maybe $S \approx \sigma.$

Comment: But I think with this Monte Carlo of $10^5$ for $z$ distribution I just showed it is different for 20, 30 and 40, and with 30 samples I got the result 0.04864 (default alternative). But yes, I will analyse your last comment in deep later.

Comment: Of course things change with increasing amounts of data, but you are interpreting simulation results improperly. There is nothing wrong with using a t test for $n = 20$ normal observations. The t test was introduced to be useful for small $n$. A t test would be OK for $n=3, 9, 15$ etc. More data increases power of finding a difference if there is a real difference to be found.

Comment: Got you idea. Just that with $n=2$ and $z$ distribution I think the *significance*  (I don't understand this term quite yet) is very low and I think below the imaginary threshold when I checked so this discredit the $n=2$ :).

Comment: No, I guess I am wrong. Just  got `0.05038` for $n=2$ and z-distribution. Thanks for your time. I thought I have understood something, but I am not.

Comment: If you simulate data according to null hypothesis, then test at 5% level, then of course, you'll reject about 5% of the time.